# Waiting for DataNitro to finish in a VBA call

Tags: python, vba, excel, datanitro

I am calling a python script from VBA with the following:

```
Sub python_call()
Application.COMAddIns("DataNitro.DataNitro").Object.RunScript ("test.py")
'do some other stuff
End Sub
```

`test.py` takes a while to run so I want VBA to wait before running the remaining code. Is there a way to do that other than `Application.Wait`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you call your VBA code from DataNitro, instead of the other way around? That'll execute synchronously.

Comment: It is assigned to a button. I don't know if I can directly call Python by clicking on a button.

Comment: It's a little roundabout, but here's how to do it:
* put all of your functionality in a python script.
* assign the button to a macro. Have that macro make one call, which calls your script.
* put any other VBA functionality in a different macro that the script can call.

Comment: Works for me. Thank you.